# ошибка ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Помогите пожалуйста, при переходе по url(http://localhost:8080/getImage?image=2.jpg) картинка показывается, а при добавлении на jsp выбивает ошибку ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING.

Контролер:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getImage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getImage(
        @RequestParam("image") String imageName,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println(imageName);
    if(!imageName.equals("")) {
        final String COMPUTER_PATH = "E:\\Projects\\dataServer\\";
        try {
            FileInputStream image = null;
            try {
                image = new FileInputStream(COMPUTER_PATH + imageName);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(image, response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error writing file to output stream. Filename was-" + imageName);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }
}
```

JSP:

```
<img src="/getImage?image=2.jpg" alt="" width="246" height="186"/>
```

Comment: не в опере не в хроме не работает, а в explorer чего-то заработало все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выдачу статики через Spring MVC приложение необходимо выполнять с использованием `ResourceHandler` и `ResourceLoader`. Конкретно в вашем случае необходимо сделать примерно следующее:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(ExampleApp.class);
    application.setWebEnvironment(true);
    application.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
    application.run(args);
  }

  @Bean
  public Path sourcesPath() {
    return Paths.get("E:/Projects/dataServer/");
  }

  @Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer webConfig(Path sourcesPath) {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
      private final String PATH_SEPARATOR = "/";
      private final String WILD_MATCH = "**";

      @Override
      public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(PATH_SEPARATOR + "media" + PATH_SEPARATOR + WILD_MATCH) //
            .addResourceLocations("file:///" + sourcesPath.toString() + PATH_SEPARATOR) //
            .resourceChain(false)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
      }

      @Override
      public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(getWebContentInterceptor());
      }

      private WebContentInterceptor getWebContentInterceptor() {
        WebContentInterceptor interceptor = new WebContentInterceptor();
        interceptor.setCacheSeconds(0);
        interceptor.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache());
        return interceptor;
      }
    };
  }

}
```

В такой конфигурации ресурсы в директории `E:\Projects\dataServer` станут доступны по пути `/media/...`.

В JSP контент также предлагается добавлять с помощью JSTL Core:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="<c:url value="/media/2.jpg" />" alt="" width="246" height="186"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

В моем (думаю, что и в Вашем) случае, нужно просто не "сбрасывать" буфер выходного потока.
Например, удрать строку:

```
response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

или в Вашем случае:

```
response.flushBuffer();
```

Дело в том, что "сбрасывая" буфер, вы инициируете отправку клиенту но при этом не формируете завершающий чанк, что-то вроде последовательности: `0\r`